# Filter blog archive by category in URL

Tags: taxonomy, archives

I've created a fairly basic form that allows users to filter post type archives by their taxonomies.

On custom post types this is super simple to do by simply setting `?taxonomy_name=term_slug` in the URL. WP also supports an array of terms with `?taxonomy_name[]=term_slug1&taxonomy_name[]=term_slug2`.

What's odd however is that on the archive for *non* custom post types (ie the "post" post type) this stops working. Setting `?category=term_slug` does absolutely nothing.

How can I, preferably without using `pre_get_posts` or anything else more advanced, filter the regular posts by their taxonomies (`category` and `post_tag`)?

Comment: You got my hopes up :) But sadly no :( I would've found it extremely strange if that worked though, because the taxonomy is named "category". I wouldn't have been _that_ surprised though seeing as this is WordPress after all :P

Comment: Not sure I follow, but `?cat=category_slug` doesn't work either.

Comment: Aaah! Thank you :) That does work. How very annoying (and WordPress:y) though. This means I'll have to handle that particular taxonomy differently from all other taxonomies. Do you know if `post_tag` too only accepts ID:s and has a different name?

Comment: Hehe ok, gaah sometimes WP drives you crazy :P Post your solution as an answer and I'll give you credit!

Comment: Since I posted it as answer I am removing my comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if default posts are stored in same table but they have different behavior and different characteristics. 
CPT has post type archive but default post type archived is called as blog and the taxonomy filter is called as tag/category archive.

You can access the category/tag archive using

For categories:

```
/?cat={category_id} //e.g. ?/cat=5
```

For tags:

```
/?tag={tag_slug} //e.g. ?/tag=my_tag_slug
```

If you are willing to use `pre_get_posts` you can customize this in the way you want (*That is what I love in WordPress <3*) else stick with default way.

Another note: I recommend to leave the default posts for blog never use them for building something custom with those types instead use CPT as many as you want to expend your site from blog to CMS :)

Comment: Annoyingly (because it's so inconsistent) enough this is correct :) So thanks. I have a follow-up question though. When going to the next page, and ending up on `/blog/page/2/`, setting `?cat={category_id}` now gives a 404 :'( Any way to fix that? This applies to both the `post` post type _and_ custom post types.

Comment: You are welcome @powerbuoy Sorry to say but I am not able to reproduce this issue. Are you sure on page 2 posts exist for in that category?

Comment: aha perhaps that's the issue. I'd prefer an empty "loop" though rather than a 404.

Comment: I will say whenever a category or tag changed reset the pagination to 1, because who knows which category has how many pages :)

Comment: That's true, but I would also like the user to be able to choose a category and _then_ navigate to the next page... we'll see how I solve it. I guess I'd need to insert ?cat, ?tag etc into the pagination links. And hope I _don't_ get a 404 :P

Comment: I'm not sure I actually tested this properly because while this still works perfectly fine for `?cat={ID}`, neither `?tag={slug}`, `?tag={ID}`, `?post_tag={slug}` or `?post_tag={ID}` seems to work. Are you sure they are supposed to?

Comment: Sorry you mixed the things. I am unable to find what is working and what not :P can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Ok so `?cat={category_id}` works fine, _but_, `?tag={tag_slug}` does not. And I've tried all kinds of variants on that (?tag=id, ?post_tag=id, ?tag=slug, ?tag=id) - none work.

Comment: Well you can check [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L18) `tag` and `cat` are valid public query parameters. If those are not working then I will say something wrong with your installation or some plugin/theme is overriding the actual query.

Comment: Hmm ok that's odd, because I've tried it on several different sites with different themes and plugins installed and it doesn't work anywhere. I'll keep digging. Thanks for your help

Comment: yw :) you can see the working example here https://wordpress.org/showcase/?tag=business

Comment: Ah ok.. that's not entirely the same thing though or is it? Because that simply redirects me to /tag/business/. I assume that ?tag=business is what the URL would be if the server lacked mod rewrite? Perhaps a better way of achieving what I'm after would be to simply use the real URLs then... so instead of `/my-custom-post-type/?my-custom-taxonomy=slug` and `/blog/?category=id` I'd simply do `/my-custom-taxonomy/slug/` and `/category/slug/`...

Comment: Yes that is correct because query string converted to permalink structure. But the point is `/?tag=slug` is equal to `/tag/slug/`. I also notice one thing in your URL `/my-custom-post-type/?my-custom-taxonomy=slug` you are mixing pretty permalink with query string. `post_type` is written in pretty permalink url and tag as query string. That is not possible :D

Comment: Actually the one with the custom post type (and blog category) works fine. And personally I prefer to "stay on the same page" and only use the form to change query parameters. It feels more "correct" to me. But seeing as ?tag doesn't work I may just switch everything to actually navigate to the correct URLs instead. Thanks again